# Why does a portion of the URL in my PHP cURL request get added to the requesting page?

Tags: php, curl

Here is my cURL request that is made from the file, **http://localhost/test.php**.

```
$endpoint = 'http://www.opensecrets.org/api/';
$params = array(
    'method' => 'candContrib',
    'apikey' => 'a5f3d10fc4afedaa161edd6556dced39',
    'cid'    => 'N00041954',
    'output' => 'json'
);
$url = $endpoint . '?' . http_build_query($params);


$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url, 
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

No response is returned, although with different code I can get the headers. The question is, why does the page URL change to this?

```
http://localhost/api/?method=candContrib&apikey=a5f3d10fc4afedaa161edd6556dced39&cid=N00041954&output=json&__cf_chl_rt_tk=wc_F3WN1i7uMCtxSArUZRkV1jTFZTHcP6o0UuT.Z2wQ-1704945973-0-gaNycGzNChA
```

Why can;t I get a response. A variation of this code was working, but has since broken. I think this had to do with changes by the API provider.

Comment: Target website is using cloud flare, and is potentially blocking your request, the `__cf_chl_rt_tk` is a hint at that. Is this API for public consumption?

Comment: @Scuzzy No, but I needed to burn it in order to post this issue.